# How do I format multiple subsequent code blocks?

Tags: support, markdown, code-formatting

I would like to display two separate blocks of code with nothing but whitespace in between. It seems that if you separate blocks with multiple line breaks, the Stack code formatter will consolidate them into a single block. I would like these two blocks:

```
Hello this is code block 1

And this is code block 2
```

to be formatted like these two blocks:

```
Hello this is code block 1
```

.

```
And this is code block 2
```

but without the intermediate dot.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can insert an HTML comment (`<!-- -->`) in between:

```
Block 1
```

```
Block 2
```

This also works with blockquotes:

> Block 1

> Block 2

Comment: Also works with just `<!-->`

Comment: @Cai: Or, indeed, *anything* that looks vaguely like an HTML tag but is not on the whitelist. `<!>` is sufficient.

Comment: @Cai one minor difference: using `<!-- -->` renders `<pre></pre><pre></pre>`, while using `<!-->` renders `<pre></pre><p></p><pre></pre>`, which is not as optimal.